# vb.net calling a c# method is giving errors

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to access c# method from a vb.net project.

The c# project has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MeF.Client;

public class LoginClass
{
    // lines of code that are giving errors  (when commented there’s no error)
    private ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext();
    public string etin;
    public string appSysId;

    static void Main(string[] args)   
    { 
        LoginClass.CreateServiceContext();
    }

    //bla, bla, bla
}
```

---

The vb.net project has this:

```vb
Imports AimEFileCore

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Process As New AimEFileCore.LoginClass
        Process.CreateServiceContext()
    End Sub
```

When running the code I get the following error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'MeFWCFClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

A Mef dll is referenced!

As soon as I comment the three lines above, it works like a charm.

Comment: Please read [ask] and share the actual errors.

Comment: Where are the errors?

Comment: What's the problem? A syntax error? A runtime exception? Once the code gets compiled there's no VB.NET or C# method, they are just methods.

Comment: If you get an exception, post the *full exception text* returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This contains the full call stack that shows where the error occured and which calls led to it. It also contains any inner exceptions that could have caused the errors.

Comment: In your vb.net project you've referenced the c# *.dll. You have to manually copy this file to your vb.net binary or set the reference to "always copy" or something like that.

Comment: As I said.  The error comes always that the three lines above aren't commented.

Comment: Your class structure looks wrong. It looks like an console app. Here is how to design classes in c# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

Comment: If your C# project references other libraries then they have to be present when you run your VB application referencing that C# library.  It would be magic for the C# library to work without its referenced libraries, wouldn't it?

Comment: @aimcorp: I'm a bit irritated about your code, as the C# code suggests that  ```CreateServiceContext()``` is ```static``` (```Shared``` in VB), but the VB sample creates an instance (```Dim Process As New AimEFileCore.LoginClass```)? By the way, I would not call it ```Process``` to avoid a conflict with the class of the same name in namespace ```System.Diagnostic```...

Comment: @aimcorp [access of shared member through an instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/access-of-shared-member-through-an-instance-qualifying-expression) is allowed in vb.net but should be underlined in green as a warning.

Comment: @aimcorp is your c# project a console app? (it looks like it because you have `static void Main(string[] args)`) You *can* reference a console app, but it's better practice to put this code in a class library. You can create a class library instead by selecting that option when creating a new project. Then you will add a reference to your class library.

Comment: @aimcorp when adding a reference, make sure you are in **References** and select **Projects \ Solution** then select your project. This will cause the referenced project to be automatically rebuilt as needed, and copied to your application's binary folder. Do not add a reference to a dll (or exe in the case of the console app) directly for which you have source code, unless you know the side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to go to Project Properties, `References` and check whether you have there a correct reference for referenced MeFWCFClient (a dll). You can add it within this dialogue, you might be able to use Nuget, or simply copy it to binary folder.

Comment: Yes, is referenced

Comment: But there's probably problem with it. Do you see the dll in the binary folder, when you compile it? Do you have correct dll for your assembly (x86, x64,...)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the method you are calling is static.  Have you tried this in vb.net?

```
AimEFileCore.LoginClass.CreateServiceContext()
```

you are instantiating LoginClass but there are no public methods defined - at least not in the code you are showing, so I've assumed it contains this:

```
public static void CreateServiceContext()
{
 ...
}
```

as that's what the C# code would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
using MeF.Client;
```

Thats the culprit.
Reference that DLL in your project.

[image]

Then on top add:

```
Imports MeF.Client
```